# Add multiple columns with map logic without using UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, apache-spark-dataset

I want to parse the address column from the given table structure using addressParser function to get number, street, city and country.

**Sample Input:**

| addressId | address |
| --- | --- |
| ADD001 | "384, East Avenue Street, New York, USA |
| ADD002 | "123, Maccolm Street, Copenhagen, Denmark" |

The sample code is attached for reference:

```
object ParseAddress extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("ParseAddress ").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  case class AddressRawData(addressId: String, address: String)

  case class AddressData(
                          addressId: String,
                          address: String,
                          number: Option[Int],
                          road: Option[String],
                          city: Option[String],
                          country: Option[String]
                        )

 def addressParser(unparsedAddress: Seq[AddressData]): Seq[AddressData] = {
    unparsedAddress.map(address => {
      val split = address.address.split(", ")

      address.copy(
        number = Some(split(0).toInt),
        road = Some(split(1)),
        city = Some(split(2)),
        country = Some(split(3))
      )
    }
    )
  }

  val addressDS: Dataset[AddressRawData] = addressDF.as[AddressRawData]

}
```

**Expected output**:

| addressId | address | number | road | city | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ADD001 | "384, East Avenue Street, New York, USA | 384 | East Avenue Street | New York | USA |
| ADD002 | "123, Maccolm Street, Copenhagen, Denmark" | 123 | Maccolm Street | Copenhagen | Denmark |

I am not sure how should I convert addressDS as an input to function to parse the column data. Some form of help to solve this problem is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think one important thing is that it's better to design your function to take a single input and return a single output (in your scenario), and if you have a collection or a dataset of rows, you can map each row to this function, that's why all these polymorphic functions (map, flatMap, fold, ...) are made, right? So you can implement a method, which receives an `AddressRawData` and returns an `AddressData`:

```scala
def singleAddressParser(unparsedAddress: AddressRawData): AddressData = {
  val split = unparsedAddress.address.split(", ")
  AddressData(
    addressId = unparsedAddress.addressId,
    address = unparsedAddress.address,
    number = Some(split(0).toInt),
    road = Some(split(1)),
    city = Some(split(2)),
    country = Some(split(3))
  )
}
```

And then map each raw data to this function:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

val addressDS: Dataset[AddressData] = 
  addressDF.as[AddressRawData].map(singleAddressParser)
```

And this is the output, as expected:

```
scala> addressDS.show(false)
+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+------------------+----------+-------+
|addressId|address                                  |number|road              |city      |country|
+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+------------------+----------+-------+
|ADD001   |384, East Avenue Street, New York, USA   |384   |East Avenue Street|New York  |USA    |
|ADD002   |123, Malccolm Street, Copenhagen, Denmark|123   |Malccolm Street   |Copenhagen|Denmark|
+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+------------------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I wanted to use the given addressParser method in the code.
 Is it possible to create a dataset with some empty columns and then replace the NULL values with the help of given method?

Comment: @Shubh yes it’s possible, provide None values and column names and everything should work fine. And if you still insist to use the addressParser function, you collect your dataset and pass it to the function, or map each row like this: address => Seq(address), and then pass it to the function